# Typical issue: css Element not found

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a typical problem with selenium Ide: [error] = * css Element not found.

I looked in the forum and I have seen very similar questions (eg, selenium-IDE-2.9.0 - [error] = li.xspPickerItem.xspPickerItemHover css Element not found), have tried to solve the problem with some of the suggested answers but I could not.

The details of my problem is as follows:

Log:

```
info] Executing: |click | css=input.select-dropdown.active | |
[error] Element css=input.select-dropdown.active not found
[info] Test case failed
```

HTML
(it contains several drop-down lists):

```
<div class="row" _ngcontent-pkb-13="">
<div class="col s2" _ngcontent-pkb-13="">
<label for="groupBy" _ngcontent-pkb-13="">Agrupado por</label>
</div> <div class="col s5" _ngcontent-pkb-13="">
<div class="select-wrapper form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid   initialized">
<span class="caret">/span>
<input class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select- options-32184002-bd89-baf2-43b8-3d88ae8219e5" value="Todo el territorio" type="text"></input>
<ul id="select-options-32184002-bd89-baf2-43b8-3d88ae8219e5"    class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
<li class=""><span>Todo el territorio</span></li><li class=""><span>Instalaciones Deportivas</span></li><li class=""><span>Parroquias</span></li><li class=""><span>Polígonos Industriales</span>
```

(it shows a small part)

How you could select any item from the drop down ?, eg. "Parroquias"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted you don't need the '.active' on the end of the locator, it should just be 'css=input.select-dropdown' However if you have multiple dropdowns this may not be the most efficient way of targetting them if they'd all have the same class. If you have control over the code you may want to add id's onto the dropdowns and use that for your target

As for getting it working, I can't get a working example on my machine as for it to appear as a dropdown you'd need your css, as you've coded it to just be a list but the css formats it as a dropdown, rather than using the 'select' tag. Normally you'd use the 'Select' command in Selenium, targetted at the dropdown, rather than a click command but I'm not sure if it would work with the way this page is coded as I've not come accross it before (my instinct would be no) so it probably would be the click on the dropdown as you're trying, then a click on the specific list item.

Comment: Yes, the flow is as you say: "...click on the dropdown as you're trying, then a click on the specific list item". |click | css=input.select-dropdown.active

Comment: I have no control over the code. Yes, the flow is as you say: "...click on the dropdown as you're trying, then a click on the specific list item": "|click | css=input.select-dropdown.active" and "|click | css=li.active> span". How I can identify the "li.active" item?

Comment: When you say active, do you mean that only 1 dropdown will be visible and others would be hidden? If so can you include the code for the 'active' dropdown and an 'inactive' one? You'd just need to find that attribute within these that differs and allows you to identify the active one. 

The '.active. command isn't one that would be recognised within Selenium IDE, the target field processes only the locators, IDE would process that as an invalid locator, as it would interpret .active as 'class named active' and you've already specified a class in 'input.select-dropdown'